# Cast int to void* and void* to int for TMemoryStream->WriteBuffer (C++Builder XE7)

Tags: c++, c++11, int, c++builder, void

I use `TMemoryStream` class and its `WriteBuffer` method for writing data to stream. I need to write and read `int` variable.

```
void __fastcall WriteBuffer(const void *Buffer, int Count)
void __fastcall ReadBuffer(void *Buffer, int Count)
```

Is following code correct or no?

**writing**:

```
int i = 5;
stream->WriteBuffer((void*)&i, sizeof(int));
```

**reading**:

```
stream->ReadBuffer((void*)&i, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Looks OK - what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is following code correct or no?

Yes.  Though the type-cast is not necessary as any pointer can be passed to a `void*` (taking `const`-correctness into account, of course):

```
int i = 5;
stream->WriteBuffer(&i, sizeof(int));
```

```
int i;
stream->ReadBuffer(&i, sizeof(int));
```